# Ubuntu Server 14.04 TLS plus Hardware RAID

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I have just completed hadrware installation of my new RAID server which will run with Ubuntu Server OS. I have installed Ubuntu Server OS and everything run seemingly without problems.

However, I have few questions, I can not find answer to anywhere. I hope, I can find them here.

**Server Info:**

- Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 TLS
- [Adaptec RAID 72405](http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/support/raid/sas_raid/sas-72405/)
- Ubuntu Server is installed on separate SATA HDD, which is not part of the Adaptec RAID field
- RAID Level 6 used

**Questions:**

1. Adaptec offers Ubuntu drivers for the RAID 72405 controller. Do I need to install them? Apparently, I can access the RAID folder. Is the Ubuntu driver needed only if the OS itself is installed on the RAID field?
2. I consider populating 50% of HDD bays now, and remaining 50% later, when needed. Will this be possible even if no Adaptec drivers are installed? After rebuilding the RAID 6, will I need to additionally increase Ubuntu partitions? Can the RAID 6 rebuild be done with all the data present, and the data won't be damaged aftr the rebuild?
3. How to correctly initialize the hardware RAID folder? Currently it it as /etc/sda on the server.

Thanks in advance.